# finding all anchor tags with pdf file as the source in php using regex or HTML parser

Tags: php, regex, anchor, html-parser

how can i find all the `anchor` tags with source pdf

```
$string="hello this is a dummy text <a href="../../abc.pdf">
```

i need only `abc.pdf` in the string variable

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) instead of regex:

```
$string='hello this is a dummy text <a href="../../abc.pdf">'; 
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($string);

$href = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
echo basename($href); // abc.pdf
```